# Problem with library loading in AWS lambda function - Python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I'm developing a python function for AWS lambda.

My function works locally, with:

```
 python-lambda-local -f handler app.py event.json -t 30
```

However, when I deploy it in **AWS Lambda**, (with a zip file with all dependencies), it seems the **objectify lib** is not loaded. 
Error message:

```
Unable to import module 'app': cannot import name 'objectify'
```

This is a snippet of my function:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import sys
import logging
import env_config
import pymysql
import traceback
import json
import requests
#from lxml import objectify
import lxml.objectify
import lxml.etree
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lxml uses code compiled in C. You need to precompile the library in the same environment that Lambda runs. Read this to understand more: https://www.azavea.com/blog/2016/06/27/using-python-lxml-amazon-lambda/

This kind person already did the job for you. Just download the precompiled library and replace in your Lambda package: https://github.com/JFox/aws-lambda-lxml

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your help !